# How can a ZMQ server process requests in batches?

Tags: python, client-server, zeromq, pyzmq

I would like to use ZMQ in a client/server model but where each server waits until it has received 100 requests, processes them jointly, and then sends out the 100 responses back to the correct clients. The reason behind this is that the server performs a computation on GPU that is only computationally efficient when performed on batches. How can this be done with ZMQ?

Below is what I tried, which unsurprisingly raises `zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state` because the server is trying to receive multiple requests in sequence without intermediately interleaving the `recv_pyobj()` calls with `send_pyobj()` responses.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time
import zmq

def computation(inputs):
  time.sleep(1)  # Simulate constant GPU overhead.
  results = np.zeros((len(inputs), 8))
  return results

def server(port, batch=100):
  context = zmq.Context()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
  socket.bind(f'tcp://*:{port}')
  while True:
    inputs = np.empty((100, 64))
    for i in range(batch):
      inputs[i] = socket.recv_pyobj()
    results = computation(inputs)
    for i in range(batch):
      socket.send_pyobj(results[i])

def client(ports):
  context = zmq.Context()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
  for port in ports:
    socket.connect(f'tcp://localhost:{port}')
  while True:
    input_ = np.zeros(64)
    socket.send_pyobj(input_)
    result = socket.recv_pyobj()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  num_clients = 10
  num_servers = 3
  ports = list(range(5550, 5550 + num_servers))
  for port in ports:
    mp.Process(target=server, args=(port,)).start()
  for _ in range(num_clients):
    mp.Process(target=client, args=(ports,)).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ROUTER` socket type combined with `recv_multipart()` and `send_multipart()` is what I was looking for. The most useful resources was the `rtreq` example under [Advanced Request-Reply Patterns](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter3/#Exploring-ROUTER-Sockets) in the official guide. Besides that, I added `msgpack` serialization and reduced the batch size because it has to be smaller than the number of clients. The working version of the snippet from the question is below.

```
import msgpack
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time
import uuid
import zmq

def computation(inputs):
  time.sleep(1)  # Simulate constant GPU overhead.
  results = np.zeros((len(inputs), 8))
  return results

def server(port, batch=10):
  context = zmq.Context.instance()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
  socket.bind(f'tcp://*:{port}')
  while True:
    inputs = np.empty((batch, 64))
    addresses = []
    for i in range(batch):
      address, empty, payload = socket.recv_multipart()
      inputs[i] = unpack(payload)
      addresses.append(address)
    print('Collected request batch.', flush=True)
    results = computation(inputs)
    for i, address in enumerate(addresses):
      payload = pack(results[i])
      socket.send_multipart([address, b'', payload])
    print('Send response batch.', flush=True)

def client(ports):
  context = zmq.Context.instance()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
  socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, uuid.uuid4().bytes)
  for port in ports:
    socket.connect(f'tcp://localhost:{port}')
  while True:
    input_ = np.zeros(64)
    socket.send(pack(input_))
    result = unpack(socket.recv())

def pack(array):
  return msgpack.packb((array.shape, str(array.dtype), array.tobytes()))

def unpack(buffer):
  shape, dtype, value = msgpack.unpackb(buffer)
  return np.frombuffer(value, dtype).reshape(shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  num_clients = 100
  num_servers = 3
  ports = list(range(5550, 5550 + num_servers))
  for port in ports:
    mp.Process(target=server, args=(port,)).start()
  for _ in range(num_clients):
    mp.Process(target=client, args=(ports,)).start()
```